# Magnetic field measured in a rotating frame

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, reference-frames, experimental-technique

Consider that we have a magnet and a magnetometer (a fluxgate magnetometer with a single coil), standing still as shown in fig 1.

[image]

In fig 1, the magnetic field measured at the axis (z<sub>1</sub>) of the magnetometer coil is  B<sub>1</sub>.

[image]

But if everything (magnet, magnetometer and the axes) was rotating together around the x axis as in fig 2, would there be a decrease in the measured magnetic field on the coil axis (z<sub>1</sub>) due to the retarded angular position ∆θ? In other words, a tilt in the opposite direction of the rotation which decreases the component of B<sub>1</sub> on the coil axis (z<sub>1</sub>)?

If so, could we state that B'<sub>1</sub>=B<sub>1</sub> cos(∆θ) ?

Can we say that this angle of tilt ∆θ is a phase shift, if we consider the rotating magnet as a transmitting and the coil as a receiving antenna?

Comment: Yes, you will find what are called spin tones in your signal from the variation in the field strength measured by the magnetometer.  For instance, see the review article by N. Ness in 1970 at http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1970SSRv...11..459N .

Comment: Thank you for the link. I understand that when a magnetometer is rotating in the presence of a magnetostatic field, a voltage is induced at a frequency which is called a "spin tone". That's because form the pespective of the magnetometer, the magnetostatic field appears as a rotating magnetic field (like a circularly polarized EM field). In fig 2 however, the magnetometer and the magnet are rotating together and from the magnetometer's perspective, the field is magnetostatic. But with a delayed angular position. It's a little hard to describe so excuse me for the long description.

Comment: Ah okay, I did not realize you were rotating the magnet too.  Is the magnet at a constant phase/angle to the magnetometer or rotating at a slightly different rate?

Comment: Magnet poles and magnetometer coil axis are constantly parallel to each other while rotating. But I think the magnetometer should be constantly "seeing" the magnet as slightly tilted (∆θ) backwards in time, because of the time delay. Could be called a "retarded angular position" of the magnetic field maybe?